# Add Publishing Pages to specfic subsites programmatically in FeatureReceiver

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, publishing-page, feature-receiver

Currently, I have created subsites programmatically in FeatureReceiver method and have a way to create publishing pages, but they are being created on the root site. Is there a way to target a specific subsite to add publishing pages to it??

Since this is in the feature receiver I am accessing the current web like this from another method using the `SPFeatureReceiver properties`

```
SPWeb spWeb = properties.GetWeb();
```

I tried something like this but was not successful:

```
        SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        {
            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = site.OpenWeb("http://www.mysite.com/newsite"))
            {
                // page creation code
            }
        }
```

Any help would be good

Comment: Could you add your page creation code as well?

Comment: What's the scope of your feature?

Comment: Its scope as Site feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All

Ended up getting things to work

After getting `SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;` I found out that all I needed to do was add the rest of the url which was could be something like "/NewPage" to the rest of the url since I already had the full site url from the properties.

Created a method that passed in the site and the weburl to get my desired result to provison the webpages

UPDATE:

Here is the code passing it these parameters:

This method is used to create the Page

```
        private void CreatePage(SPSite site1, string cWebUrl, string cPageLayout, string cPageName, string cPageTitle)
        {
        try
        {
            using (SPWeb spoWeb = site1.OpenWeb(cWebUrl))
            {
                PublishingWeb pWebRoot = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(site1.RootWeb);
                PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(spoWeb);
                PageLayout[] layouts = pWebRoot.GetAvailablePageLayouts();
                PageLayout pl = GetPageLayout(layouts, cPageLayout);
                if (pl != null)
                {
                    //Create My Pages
                    PublishingPage newPage = pWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(cPageName, pl);
                    newPage.Layout = pl;
                    newPage.Title = cPageTitle;
                    newPage.Update();
                    newPage.CheckIn("");
                    pWeb.Update();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error Handling code
        }
    }
```

Then I created another method where I passed in the values to all the pages I wanted to create:

```
        private void CreatePages(SPSite site)
        {
           CreatePage(site, "/", "MyPage1.Minimal..aspx", "Page1.aspx", "Page1");
           CreatePage(site, "/", "MyPage2.Minimal.aspx", "Page2.aspx", "Page2");
           CreatePage(site, "/", "MyPage3.Minimal.aspx", "Sitemap.aspx", "Sitemap");
        }
```

Comment: Post your code, and have another upvote!

Comment: Will do Robert..

Comment: Hmmm ... I'd like to see it too, since I have to solve this exact problem. TIA, Josh

Comment: Josh, I am going to chastise him via email for not adding it yet.

Comment: Posted code in my answer above